# Jenkins Maven Build Not Picking Up Java Home

Tags: java, jenkins, maven-3

The version of Jenkins I am using seems to not be correctly picking up the value for Java Home that I am setting as a Global Variable

if I run a clean install on my pom as a Pre Build Step - it picks up the Java Home variable that I set
If I run a clean install on my pom as a Build step - it picks up another version of Java on my linux box thats not set as Java Home

I have tried a few things including deleting the version of Java that the Build Step is picking up but to no avail. For now I will execute my build as a Pre Build step until I have figured out the problem

The version of jenkins I am using is Jenkins ver. 1.565.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you configured the JDK installation under Manage Jenkins Global Configuration?

Have you configured your maven job to use that particular JDK? (If you have just one, it will always use that one)

Jenkins will install and maintain it's own JDK, independent of what you have pre-installed on the operating system